# How to suspend a process in Windows foreground process?

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe

How to suspend in the Windows foreground process with the same name Stalk.exe? But there are 2 of them running. The background minimized process with the same name does not need to be stopped. I want to do it through the batch file cmd. For example:

pssuspend Stalk.exe Background

pssuspend Stalk.exe Forward - This one needs to be suspended but not turned off

Comment: In Admin Tools, Services, you can Stop a service and then later Resume it. Does that do what you wish?

Comment: Are "background" and "Forward" command line options to the process?  How can you identify these processes in order to get the PID of the correct one to call pssuspend with the PID rather than name? Command line arguments for example? Is one the child of the other for example?  Do they run as the same user? Etc.;

Comment: Both processes are running from the same user. But the first before launching the second was transferred to the virtual desktop on this PC. After the transfer, I launch the second one, and I need to suspend the second one. I can restart manually.